# How to authorise android app to only one device?

Tags: android, authorization, apk, device

I will be selling the app I have created. Directly by sending apk to customers.
They will pay for subscription, yearly or quarterly.
How can I make sure in the easiest way to lock an app to single device.
Was thinking of an app generating a string based on time of install and me sending them unlock key for that string.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the device fingerprint with [this library](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs-android)
and on app launch call your api with this id as param,
Return true if the id is valid (subscription active)
else return false

In app if true: continue
else: Show contact us non dismissable popup

Comment: I've just edited nine of your answers where you ask for upvotes. Asking for upvotes is considered noise and should not be posted - see, e.g. [Is it okay to ask for upvotes in a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323847/1364007) which talks about questions - but the premise is the same: don't do it.

Comment: SO Too strict  -_-